# rsync - How can I exclude from all instances of a file while using relative paths for each file?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I am coding a deployment script that uses `rsync` to sync cloned repository files with a website target directory. I am trying to allow my users the ability to place a `.exclude` file anywhere in their repository that would allow them to exclude files on a relative path basis.

For example, if a user has a sub directory named `folder` in their repository with a file named `.dontdeploythis` inside of it, they should be able to place a `.exclude` file right next to it with the contents of `.dontdeploythis` instead of having a `.exclude` file in the top level of the repository with the contents of `folder/.dontdeploythis`.

I ran across some article explaining how I can do this, but I can't find it again for the life of me.

If you have any answers, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `--exclude-from` for each .exclude files as found in  dir tree. `find` command can be use full as -

```
In below example I've files to ignore like "ignore1|2|3"
[root@puppetmaster ~]# find . -xdev -name ig*
./folder/folder2/ignore2
./folder/folder3/ignore3
./folder/ignore1
```

I've included them in .exclude in their respective dir

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# find . -xdev -name  .exclude
./folder/folder2/.exclude
./folder/folder3/.exclude
./folder/.exclude
```

Now find all the .exclude in all dir

```
[root@puppetmaster folder]# for i in `find . -xdev -name .exclude`; do echo -n "--exclude-from $i "; done > /tmp/test
```

Assign all --exclude-from strings to J

```
J=`cat /tmp/test`

[root@puppetmaster folder]# rsync -avz --exclude .exclude  $J  . /tmp/testing/
sending incremental file list
./
test1
folder2/
folder2/test2
folder3/
folder3/test3

sent 239 bytes  received 80 bytes  638.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

I'm just giving you a quick logic I've in mind, this has worked for me on a quick test. Hope it helps you scripting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use per-directory rules for this.

```
rsync -av --filter=':e- .exclude' /some/path/ remote:/dest/
```

rsync will then look in each directory whethere there is a .exclude file, and if so, treat the patterns in it as an exclude list (that's what the `-` does, you can also leave out the `-` and then the contents would be used as a general filter file; but that would be confusing with a file named `.exclude`). The `e` after the `:` means that the file itself is also excluded from the transfer.

In your example the contents of `.exclude` would be:

```
/.dontdeploythis
```

The leading slash means that the name is only matched inside the directory itself, and not in any subdirectory.